# IOS - Check if Youtube Video exists using Youtube API

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

I have searched but could not find any articles on how to check if youtube videos exist using youtube api and objective-c how can this be done in code?

### EDIT

I have tried this but i keep getting an Error 400 back from youtube:

```
GDataQueryYouTube * query = [[GDataQueryYouTube alloc] init];

        query.feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=%@", textFieldYoutube.text]];

        GDataServiceGoogleYouTube * service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

        service.userAgent = @"xxx";

        [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error)
         {
             if(!error)
             {
             NSArray * entries = feed.entries;

             if(entries.count)
             {
                 GDataEntryYouTubeVideo * firstVideo = entries[0];
             }
             }

 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should request to this URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=%@&key=%@,yourVideoId,yourYoutubeAPIKey
```

After request this URL you will get some json response like

```
    2016-08-10 11:14:44.157 YourApp[10127:86552] {
    etag = "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/rBQu-ew0vFUVDl87HWqheTjFeZ4\"";
    items =     (
                {
            etag = "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/qO4hLAd6uXnb116ECPtCa2RwNxM\"";
            id = zhDsNTmoENc;
            kind = "youtube#video";
            status =             {
                embeddable = 1;
                license = youtube;
                privacyStatus = public;
                publicStatsViewable = 1;
                uploadStatus = processed;
            };
        }
    );
    kind = "youtube#videoListResponse";
    pageInfo =     {
        resultsPerPage = 1;
        totalResults = 1;
    };
}

2016-08-10 11:14:44.153 YourApp[10127:86568] {
etag = "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/OWcvT3ot9zyYa1s4P5GWh8yMPIQ\"";
items =     (
            {
        etag = "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/NpmRcx9OpHgA2LoHqiki1KznNHc\"";
        id = HV4JYMQTsOU;
        kind = "youtube#video";
        status =             {
            embeddable = 1;
            license = youtube;
            privacyStatus = public;
            publicStatsViewable = 1;
            rejectionReason = length;
            uploadStatus = rejected;
        };
    }
);
kind = "youtube#videoListResponse";
pageInfo =     {
    resultsPerPage = 1;
    totalResults = 1;
};
```

}

This is the response json from 2 videos
You will see in 2 json, the different is **`uploadStatus`** (one is `processed` and one is `rejected`).
This field will let you know which youtube video is available. And there are 5 values for `uploadStatus`:

> deleted, failed, processed, rejected, uploaded

```
NSString *videoStatus = [responseJson[@"items"] objectAtIndex:0][@"status"][@"uploadStatus"];

if([videoStatus isEqualToString:@"deleted"] || [videoStatusisEqualToString:@"failed"] || [videoStatus isEqualToString:@"rejected"]){

}
```